# Transform 87x2 matrix into 29x6 in R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose if I have a matrix with dimension `87x2`. How can I convert into the dimension `29x6` in `r`

```
set.seed(1)
mat1 = matrix(runif(174), 87, 2)
```

I wanted to have like this below

```
> matrix(c(1:12), 6, 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    7
[2,]    2    8
[3,]    3    9
[4,]    4   10
[5,]    5   11
[6,]    6   12
> matrix(c(1:12), 2, 6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(1:12), 6, 2)
matrix(mat1, nrow = 2, ncol = 6)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12
```

Or set the dimensions directly using `dim`

```
dim(mat1) <- c(2, 6)
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying this way. `va = c(seq(1, 87, by = 29))
DF2 <- mapply(function(a, b) mat1[a:b, ], va, c(va[-1], nrow(mat1)), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
DF2`. I created the list here. However in the first two list I have 30 elements. It is not allowing me to use `do.call("cbind", DF2)`. Are there any way to solve this?

Comment: @score324 Why? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. You can simply "reshape" a `matrix` by setting its dimensions with `dim` (or reshape within `matrix` as I demonstrate in my alternative).

Comment: I want arrange it in stack way

Comment: @score324 That's not clear at all from your post. Please give a **minimal** & reproducible example including **expected output**. Try and use a smaller sample matrix to demonstrate.

Comment: I have added an example. I need to transform `87x2` matrix into `29x6`, without changing the order of the values. Thanks.

Comment: @score324 Thanks that helps. I have updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: You can even drop the `as.numeric()` - a matrix is just a vector with some dimensions so `matrix(mat1,nrow=2,ncol=6)` will do the job.

Comment: @thelatemail Ah yes, thanks for the clarification. I've simplified my answer.